# Spartacus Breakpoint Configuration

Tags: breakpoints, spartacus-storefront

I am trying to use a custom breakpoint config. Since there is no real documentation, I checked the code of the BreakpointService. As far as I understand, I should be able to do a custom breakpoint config like this as part of the `SpartacusConfigurationModule`:

```
providers: [
   provideConfig(<LayoutConfig>{
      breakpoints: {
        [BREAKPOINT.xs]: {
          max: 767,
        },
        [BREAKPOINT.sm]: {
          min: 768,
          max: 959,
        },
        [BREAKPOINT.md]: {
          min: 960,
          max: 1199,
        },
        [BREAKPOINT.lg]: {
          min: 1200,
          max: 1679,
        },
        [BREAKPOINT.xl]: {
          min: 1680,
        }
      },
   }
]
```

After adding the above config and using the breakpoint service, I still get the default breakpoints hardcoded into the spartacus code.

As soon as I add the following Code to my `app.module.ts`, it works correctly:

```
   imports: [
      ConfigModule.withConfig(<LayoutConfig>{// above config}),
   ]
```

Any Idea why provideConfig within the `SpartacusFeatureModule` is not enough?

Comment: When you say "adding the above config" to SpartacusConfigurationModule file, do you mean importing adding to the providers using provideConfig?

Comment: @RaminAhmadi exactly, when using `provideConfig` it does not seem to get applied, when using the `ConfigModule` (Which is legacy according to the docs https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/global-configuration-in-spartacus/#configmodulewithconfig) it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR

Provide your custom layout config after the `BaseStorefrontModule`.

#### Explanation

All the config chunks are deep-merged in the order of being provided.

Because the `SpartacusConfigurationModule` in your app is imported before `BaseStorefrontModule` (which inside provides the default layout), the default config "wins" and overwrite your config. So to fix the problem, your layout config needs to be provided after the Spartacus' module `BaseStorefrontModule` is imported.

See the implementation of OOTB `SpartacusModule` in your app:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    SpartacusFeaturesModule,
    SpartacusConfigurationModule, // <-- your custom layout config is provided inside
    BaseStorefrontModule // <-- it imports inside LayoutModule which provides the default layout config

    // ... the last provided config wins

  ],
  exports: [BaseStorefrontModule]
})
export class SpartacusModule { }
```

#### Spartacus issue

In general you shouldn't be concerned about the priority of default configs vs. custom configs, because Spartacus provides most of the config chunks via `provideDefaultConfig()`, which by design has a lower priority than custom config chunks. Unfortunately at the moment of writing there a few leftovers using `provideConfig()` inside source code of spartacus libs, which makes them competing in priority with custom configs. It's the case for example for the default layout config (see implementation of [LayoutModule](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/e62698ba57bca859c31c487f0de86cf44f6e17d2/projects/storefrontlib/layout/layout.module.ts#L16)).

The issue is tracked in the ticket https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/15621

Comment: Hi Krzysztof, thanks for the detailed explanation of what happened.. I am actually not sure, why the BaseStorefrontModule has been at the last position of the imports, fixed that now and it works perfectly. BR Jan

Comment: Hi Krzysztof, I figured out, why BaseStorefrontModule was imported last, it seems like generating a fresh version of spartacus put's it at the end of the imports array, which is obviously not ideal..